# Table generated in a new page?

Tags: floats

I'm writing a paper, using the IEEE package. The paper is formatted in 2 columns. I want the table to go after the text of table 1, in the right column. What ends up happening is the table pops to a new page. Below is my code + a screenshot of what it looks like. Is there a way to do it other than screenshotting the table and putting it in as a figure?

```
\subsection{Supplemental Tables}
Supplemental Table 1. Primers used for qPCR
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l| p{2.75cm}|p{2.75cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Gene}   & \textbf{Forward}                       & \textbf{Reverse}                        \\ \hline
\textit{RPL32}  & 5’- CAA CAT TGG TTA TGG AAG CAA CA -3’ & 5’- TGA CGT TGT GGA CCA GGA ACT -3’     \\ \hline
\textit{COL1A1} & 5’- GCC AAG ACG AAG ACA TCC CA -3’     & 5’- GGC AGT TCT TGG TCT CGT CA -3’      \\ \hline
\textit{ASPN}   & 5’- TGC GAA GGC TGT ATC TGT CC -3’     & 5’- GAA CAC CGT CAC CCC TTC AA-3’       \\ \hline
\textit{POSTN}  & 5’- GGA GGC AAA CAG CTC AGA GT -3’     & 5’- AAT CGC ACC GTT TCT CCC TT -3’      \\ \hline
\textit{ALPL}   & 5’- CAC GGG CAC CAT GAA GGA AAA G -3’  & 5’- TGG CGC AGG GGC ACA GGA GAC T -3’   \\ \hline
\textit{RUNX2}  & 5’- ATG CTT CAT TCG CCT CAC AAA C -3’  & 5’- CCA AAA GAA GTT TTG CTG ACA TGG -3’ \\ \hline
\textit{CEMP1}  & 5’- TGG TTC TTC CCT -GGC TGT TC -3’    & 5’- GGC TCT GCC ACT GTT CTC TT -3’      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image: What it looks like now]

Comment: you have used `table*`  so that is a two-column span that comes on the next page at the earliest. Did you intend `table` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. I guessing, that you looking for one from the following solutions:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Supplemental Tables (1. example)}
Supplemental Table 1. Primers used for qPCR
    \begin{table*}[b]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\itshape}l  X X @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Gene}   & \textbf{Forward}                       & \textbf{Reverse}                 \\
    \midrule
RPL32   & 5’- CAA CAT TGG TTA TGG AAG CAA CA -3’ & 5’- TGA CGT TGT GGA CCA GGA ACT -3’     \\ 
COL1A1  & 5’- GCC AAG ACG AAG ACA TCC CA -3’     & 5’- GGC AGT TCT TGG TCT CGT CA -3’      \\ 
ASPN    & 5’- TGC GAA GGC TGT ATC TGT CC -3’     & 5’- GAA CAC CGT CAC CCC TTC AA-3’       \\ 
POSTN   & 5’- GGA GGC AAA CAG CTC AGA GT -3’     & 5’- AAT CGC ACC GTT TCT CCC TT -3’      \\ 
ALPL    & 5’- CAC GGG CAC CAT GAA GGA AAA G -3’  & 5’- TGG CGC AGG GGC ACA GGA GAC T -3’   \\ 
RUNX2   & 5’- ATG CTT CAT TCG CCT CAC AAA C -3’  & 5’- CCA AAA GAA GTT TTG CTG ACA TGG -3’ \\ 
CEMP1   & 5’- TGG TTC TTC CCT -GGC TGT TC -3’    & 5’- GGC TCT GCC ACT GTT CTC TT -3’      \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum[2-6]
\subsection{Supplemental Tables (2. example}
Supplemental Table 1. Primers used for qPCR
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\itshape}l | X | X |}
    \hline
\textbf{Gene}   & \textbf{Forward}                       & \textbf{Reverse}                 \\
    \hline
RPL32   & 5’- CAA CAT TGG TTA TGG AAG CAA CA -3’ & 5’- TGA CGT TGT GGA CCA GGA ACT -3’      \\ \hline
COL1A1  & 5’- GCC AAG ACG AAG ACA TCC CA -3’     & 5’- GGC AGT TCT TGG TCT CGT CA -3’       \\ \hline
ASPN    & 5’- TGC GAA GGC TGT ATC TGT CC -3’     & 5’- GAA CAC CGT CAC CCC TTC AA-3’        \\ \hline
POSTN   & 5’- GGA GGC AAA CAG CTC AGA GT -3’     & 5’- AAT CGC ACC GTT TCT CCC TT -3’       \\ \hline
ALPL    & 5’- CAC GGG CAC CAT GAA GGA AAA G -3’  & 5’- TGG CGC AGG GGC ACA GGA GAC T -3’    \\ \hline
RUNX2   & 5’- ATG CTT CAT TCG CCT CAC AAA C -3’  & 5’- CCA AAA GAA GTT TTG CTG ACA TGG -3’  \\ \hline
CEMP1   & 5’- TGG TTC TTC CCT -GGC TGT TC -3’    & 5’- GGC TCT GCC ACT GTT CTC TT -3’       \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The second one is what I'm looking for/trying to ask for. For future reference, can I ask what was unclear so I know to phrase my questions better?

Comment: @srm, unclear is table size. Is it in one column or over two column. Your code suggest that it should be over two column, image shows that it is in one column ... You should provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem. If answer solve your problem, you can up-vote and accept it (by clicking on up-pen and check mark at top left side of answer) :-)